# Build & Run: plist is not getting updated

Tags: xcode4, plist

I have a plist in my resource bundle which I copy by folder reference. For some reason, my edited & saved (in Xcode) plist is not getting copied/updated until I delete the app. Otherwise the old plist (before editing) is copied over, even though I delete the app. Is data being left over?

The plist is edited quite often, so debugging is very time-consuming this way. How can I make sure the plist is copied properly?

Comment: uninstall and reinstalling solved my problem in debug environment... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you copying the plist file in Documents folder? if you are copying that then you must delete the app from iPhone simulator every time you launch the app.

You can also do one thing.. you can copy the file in documents folder every time you launch the app. 
Because the document folder's content can only be delete by deleting the app from simulator/device.

Then there is no need to restart the simulator/device and xcode.

Comment: The plist is copied in the resource bundle, not in Documents. So I would expect the resource data to be deleted when the app is deleted, but deleting the app alone does not do it.

Comment: No the data from resource can not be deleted you have to delete it manually. BTW: if you are not copying the file in Documents then you will not be able to edit it.

Comment: I should make clear that editing is done in Xcode, not runtime.

Comment: then you have to always delete it manually from xcode ... drag the new plist file and also delete the app from simulator.. there is no other way!

Comment: It's not a new plist file though. I'm simply editing & saving to the existing plist, but for whatever reason the edit is not reflected.

Comment: then try to delete the app from simulator and clean build and run

Comment: Ok the restart was not needed, but I still need to delete the app for the edit to be reflected. Maybe it has something to do with the folder reference, rather than copying.

Comment: I think its related to the Mac/iPhone file system .. if a file already exist there from the old program then the os does not copy that file from the new setup/program.  I faced this issue while working on a mac project. I create the pkg file from app and install it on my computer. When I change some resource in the program create setup file and install it again (without completely remove the previous version) the new files are not getting replaced. I had to delete the previous setup mantaully

Comment: I guess that is what's happening, and if so I need to delete the app each time.

Comment: I found cleaning the build shift+cmd+k did the trick but it seems quite fickle

Answer (score 0):

This is a laaate answer; but hey, the OP did not mark a correct answer, so here is my solution. I created two property lists. The first one is debugging information, like constant numbers, strings and booleans. I called this property list `SETTINGS.plist`. My other plist is the one that I use to save game data. Since the SETTINGS plist is the one I update through the xcode interface, I update it every time I run the app.

```
-(void)setUpPlist{

listPath = [[self docsDir] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SETTINGS.plist"];

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:listPath]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SETTINGS" ofType:@"plist"] toPath:listPath error:nil];

}
else {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:listPath error:nil];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SETTINGS" ofType:@"plist"] toPath:listPath error:nil];
}

savedData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:listPath];
}

-(NSString *)docsDir{
return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Here, listPath is of `NSString` type and savedDate is of `NSMutableDictionary` type. Hope this helps.